# ¿Qué es un usuario anónimo?

Tags: soporte, ediciones-sugeridas, usuarios-nuevos

Recientemente he visto en las colas de revisión ediciones sugeridas por usuarios anónimos y me llega esta pregunta.

Ademas ¿Para que sirve loguearse de manera anónima?

Answer (score 3):

En este contexto, un usuario anonimo, es un usuario **que no se ha logeado** pero que ha sugerirdo una edicion/mejora de algun post (por eso es anonima).

Este tipo de ediciones entran en la cola de *ediciones sugeridas* y en el lugar donde habitualmente aparece el nombre de usuario que edito el post, dice "usuario anonimo".

Puedes verificarlo abriendo una pregunta en una ventana de incognito y tocando el link que dice `mejorar esta pregunta` o `mejorar esta respuesta` segun sea el caso. Se encuentra debajo del post, donde usualmente esta el boton `editar`.

Ojo que en meta no existen dichos links.